# Which Android API to use for all device compatibility?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have `downloaded SDK for Android 4.4(API Level 19)` and `developed one android app`.

But on `some old devices` it is `crashed` as they are `using OS (Android 4.0 and lesser)`

I have already specified below then also it is crashed on old OS devices

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```

> Is there any other setting I need to do to run my app on old devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the minSdkVersion and TargetSDKVersion isn't enough. In every new Android release new API's and classes are introduced in the SDK. However older versions of Android don't have these new changes. This is the reason the Android team have introduced the Android Support Library, this enables backward compatibiliteit of new features on the older Android versions. My guess is that you're using API's and/or classes only available in the newer SDKs.

Please reffer to: [Support Library | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

Comment: how do I install or add old api's in my app?

Comment: Basically you should add the Support Library to your app and use the classes and API's inside this library instead of the SDK ones. For example: you no longer use the FragmentManager, instead you use the SupportFragmentManager. To compile your app against a older platform you should set the targetSdkVersion to the older platform, this way you will get errors when classes aren't available at that certain SDK version.